# Format cells between two dates with a color of Range B4

Tags: excel, vba

I have wrote a code and I want to use conditional formatting to highlight each cell within a row of dates between two dates of Cell `C8` , `D8` and Percentage `B8`.

I have added a below pictures where i have been using Conditional Formatting but i want to perform this task through VBA.

Below picture is highlighting the cells based on dates of `C8` , `D8` and its progress `B8`.

I want to add one more thing that Code will popup the color in between dates which is available in cell `B4`

I have wrote this piece of code but unable to complete this if someone could help to complete it. I will really appreciate the help.

```
Sub updcolor()

    Dim rngDates As Range
    Dim startd As Range
    Dim endd As Range
    Dim prog As Range
    Dim color As Range
    
    Set startdt = Sheet1.Range("C8")
    Set enddt = Sheet1.Range("D8")
    Set prog = Sheet1.Range("B8")
    Set color = Sheet1.Range("B4")
    Set rngDates = Sheet1.Range("I4:BJ4")

    Dim rngDateCell As Range
    For Each rngDateCell In rngDates.Cells
    
    If Sheet1.Cells(rngDateCell.Row, 4).Value <= rngDateCell.Value And _
    Sheet1.Cells(rngDateCell.Row, 4).Value >= rngDateCell.Value Then
    rngDateCell.Interior.ColorIndex = Sheet1.range("B4")
          
            
    End If
    Next rngDateCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume row 4 has dates although you only show the day number.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub updcolor()

    Const DATE_RNG As String = "G4:BJ4"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Long, pcent As Single
    Dim rng As Range, color As Integer
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    color = Sheet1.Range("B4").Interior.ColorIndex
    
    Dim dtStart As Date, dtEnd As Date, dtEndBar As Date
    Dim dur As Integer
    
    ' scan down sheet
    For r = 8 To 11
        pcent = ws.Cells(r, "B")
        dtStart = ws.Cells(r, "C")
        dtEnd = ws.Cells(r, "D")
        dur = DateDiff("d", dtStart, dtEnd) + 1
       
        dtEndBar = DateAdd("d", Int(dur * pcent) - 1, dtStart)
        'ws.Cells(r, "A") = dtEndBar
        
        ' scan across dates
        For Each rng In ws.Range(DATE_RNG)
            
            If rng >= dtStart And rng <= dtEndBar Then
               ws.Cells(r, rng.Column).Interior.ColorIndex = color
            Else
               ws.Cells(r, rng.Column).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            End If
            
        Next  
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Comment: If i want to add RGB instead of Cell reference for popup the Color. how it would done. @CDP1802 can you please share.

Comment: @mento https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rgb-function

Comment: Thank you. @CDP1802